# Joining lines with same field

Tags: text-processing, awk, join

I've two files in this form:

```
File1: id:0.0260509118455
File2: id:X:Y
```

I'd like to get a third file having all lines of file1 joined with the lines of second file containing the same id. 
i.e. :

```
File3: id:0.0260509118455:X:Y
```

(file1 has 100 lines, file2 has 666 lines).
 There are not unpairable lines

Answer (score 2):

To join files containing database tables, use the `join` command after sorting the tables into key order:

```
sort -b -t : file1 > sorted-file1
sort -b -t : file2 > sorted-file2
join -t : sorted-file1 sorted-file2
```

## Further reading

- ["Utilities: join"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html).  *Shell Command Language*.  Single UNIX Specification.  Issue 7.
  IEEE 1003.1.  2016.  The Open Group.
- [Merge files using a common column value](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347645/)

Comment: what if I want the line sorted not by id but by the numerical field of File1 ?

Comment: Then you use the `sort` command on the joined output.

Comment: Why not `join -t: <(sort -b -t: file1) <(sort -b -t: file2)` to eliminate the need of extra files?

Comment: Because the question is not specific to merely those particular shells where that would actually work, and because for all we know the need for extra files is _already_ eliminated and the files are already in sort order.  In the more straightforward form given, it's simpler for readers to work out how to take out the redundant sort steps, when they are in fact redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You should able to do this with the "paste" command.
It reads the columns instead of lines.

```
awk -F: '{ print $2}' File2 > File4
```

To remove the id: tag

Then

```
paste  File1 File4 > File3
```

Should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with awk, checking the id, without the need to sort or to pre-process the files in any way:

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}$1 in a {print a[$1],$2,$3}' OFS=: file1 file2 >file3
```

PS: To gain performance small file (file1 100 lines) is loaded first in memory, and big file is compared against memory.